# How to integrate Postman with Git on local machine

Tags: git, postman

Is there a way by which I can use Git as version control for Collections and other Postman artifacts like environment files. Since collections are stored as JSON this should be easily doable. I don't want to export collection every time I change it just to be able to put it in my git repo.

For example, when I code in Intellij/eclipse to edit a Java file, I can easily use git as version control by creating a git repo where my workspace is. Similarlly, what I looking for in Postman is that when I edit a collection or environment in Postman desktop app, I should be able to commit the json file and push it to my repo as I can in other scenrio.

I know there is a version control provided by Postman itself. I know there is an integration available with Github and Gitlab. But these options are either dependent on Postman or have a complexity which is not required for such simple usecase.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you find a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check their official documentation..
https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-data/#importing-via-github-repositories

for more info..
https://learning.postman.com/docs/integrations/available-integrations/github/

Comment: Thank you for these links. Yes, this is what I was looking for but it seems it is all paid (`enterprise`, `ultimate`, `paid`).